# How to select distinct email engine provider from database (SQL server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Suppose a table is having lots of email Ids. We need the distinct email engine service providers. Like for an example..

```
id | EmailID
-------------
1  | aa@gmail.com
2  | bb@yahoo.com
3  | cc@outlook.com
4  | dd@aol.com
5  | ee@gmail.com
```

So we saw, four(4) distinct email ID providers are there Gmail,Yahoo,Outlook,AOL.
What SQL query should we use to find out the distinct email engine provider (i.e. where    this EmailID after '@' are different and could be same after .com)

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select Distinct substring(EmailID,charindex('@',EmailID,1)+1,len(EmailId))
from Table1
```

If you want extract only words like `gmail,yahoo,outlook,outlook`

Then try the below `Query`.

```
select 
Distinct 
substring(EmailID,
        charindex('@',EmailID,1)+1,
        charindex('.',EmailID,charindex('@',EmailID,1)+1)-charindex('@',EmailID,1)-1)
from Table1
```